# Fortran: Interpreting "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: linker, fortran

When compiling a program, I am shown the following error messages:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_jrand_", referenced from:
      ___trfind_module_MOD_trfind in ccqRBw2L.o
     (maybe you meant: ___jrand_module_MOD_jrand)
  "_left_", referenced from:
      ___trmesh_module_MOD_trmesh in ccq56SyA.o
     (maybe you meant: ___left_module_MOD_left)
  "_lstptr_", referenced from:
      ___intadd_module_MOD_intadd in ccr7Tz7x.o
      ___swap_module_MOD_swap in cclq1Td3.o
      ___trfind_module_MOD_trfind in ccqRBw2L.o
      ___addnod_module_MOD_addnod in ccwGNCEK.o
     (maybe you meant: ___lstptr_module_MOD_lstptr)
  "_store_", referenced from:
      ___trfind_module_MOD_trfind in ccqRBw2L.o
     (maybe you meant: ___store_module_MOD_store)
  "_swptst_", referenced from:
      ___addnod_module_MOD_addnod in ccwGNCEK.o
     (maybe you meant: ___swptst_module_MOD_swptst)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I understand that this comes about because of incorrect linking between modules. My question is how exactly to interpret the information the compiler is giving. What does "in ccqRBw2L.o" mean, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you the most important are the suggestions `maybe you meant`.

It as very probable you forgot to `use` the relevant modules. In particular

```
"_jrand_", referenced from:
      ___trfind_module_MOD_trfind in ccqRBw2L.o
     (maybe you meant: ___jrand_module_MOD_jrand)
```

when linking the object file `ccqRBw2L.o` (the name is controlled by your build mechanism, some Makefile or similar) the linker did not find any symbol `_jrand_` which would be an external subroutine or function called `jrand`.

However the linker sees that there is something called `jrand`.

```
     maybe you meant: ___jrand_module_MOD_jrand
```

but it is not external, it seems to be located in the module called `jrand`.

You should make sure you use the module (`use jrand`) when calling the subroutine or function which is in this module.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. The background to this is that there is a function called jrand, which exists in a separate file called jrand_module.f90

Comment: The file name is not really relevant. The point is that the function is inside a module, which happens to be in that file.

Comment: I'm quite familiar with "use [module]" in order to call subroutines within the module from a program, but somehow calling the function jrand is proving to be trickier than with subroutines. Following an example I found, I have altered the linking method to "real, external :: jrand" instead of "use jrand_module" and am now given error messages complaining of an "ambiguous reference". Sorry if that's all confusing, hopefully I'll work it out.

Comment: It is not an external procedure, it is a module procedure. You must not declare it as external, you must use the module.